# Compact space and Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

A continuous map from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is closed. Why this is true?

Help me please I want to learn why this is correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Combine the following facts:

1) A closed subspace of a compact space is compact.

2) A continuous map always maps compact spaces onto compact spaces.

3) Compact subspaces of Hausdorff spaces are closed.

Comment: Thanks @Martin Brandenburg :))

Comment: Is there any reason to talk about subspaces instead of subsets here?

Comment: Yes, but the comment box is too small for a digression on category theory ;). Sets have no topology, therefore "compact set" is absolute nonsense (but unfortunately quite common, *sigh*).

Answer (score 7):

If $f:X\to Y$ is continuous and $K\subseteq X$ is compact then $f(K)$ is compact.

Now use that closed subsets of compact sets are compacts and that compact subsets of Hausdorff spaces are closed.